# Search bar for external API in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, api, jscript

**My error is: 'search' is assigned a value but never used.** But I don't know if it's needed and if so, where to place it.

Everything works and the search bar appears above my table, but it seems like my search bar is not linked with my table and I cannot search for anything.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react"; 
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css"; 
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"; 
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {Button, Badge} from "reactstrap";

export default function App() { 
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);  
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(""); 

  const columns = [ 
  { headerName: "Title", field: "title" }, 
  { headerName: "Author", field: "author" }, 
  { headerName: "Edition Count", field: "editionCount" }, 
  { headerName: "Book ID", field: "id" } 
];  

useEffect(() => { 
  fetch("https://openlibrary.org/subjects/drama.json?published_in=2000") 
    .then(res => res.json()) 
    .then(data => data.works) 
    .then(works =>  
       works.map(book => { 
        return { 
          title: book.title, 
          author: book.authors[0].name, 
          editionCount: book.edition_count, 
          id: book.cover_id 
        }; 
    }) 
  ) 
  .then(books => setRowData(books)); 
}, []); 

return ( 
  <div className="container"> 
    <h1>Book Catalogue</h1> 
    <SearchBar onSubmit={setSearch} />
    <p> 
      <Badge colour="success">{rowData.length}</Badge> Books published in 2000 
      in the Drama category 
    </p> 
    <div 
       className="ag-theme-balham" 
       style={{ 
          height: "300px", 
        width: "800px" 
         }} 
    > 
        <AgGridReact 
          columnDefs={columns}  
        rowData={rowData}  
        pagination={true} 
        paginationPageSize={7} 
        /> 
    </div> 
    <Button 
      colour="info" 
      size="sm" 
      className="mt-3" 
      href="https://openlibrary.org/developers/api" 
      target="_blank" 
    > 
      Go to Open Library API 
    </Button> 
  </div> 
)
}; 

function SearchBar(props) { 
    const [innerSearch, setInnerSearch] = useState(""); 
    return ( 
      <div> 
        <input 
          aria-labelledby="search-button" 
          name="search" 
          id="search" 
          type="search" 
          value={innerSearch} 
          onChange={e => setInnerSearch(e.target.value)} 
        />  
  
        <button 
          id="search-button" 
          type="button" 
          onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerSearch)} 
        > 
          Search 
        </button> 
      </div> 
    ); 
  }
```

Are there any templates or even tutorials out there that can be used to get this done? I've gone over a couple and changed my code at least half a dozen times so far but the result is the same so I know I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You can check the antd library which has search and filter included for the table. https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but what are you trying to do? If you're trying to filter through the data you've already fetched you should use the filter method as such:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
  fetch("https://openlibrary.org/subjects/drama.json?published_in=2000") 
    .then(res => res.json()) 
    .then(data => data.works)
    .then(data => data.filter(book => book.title.includes(search))
    .then(...)
```

or maybe you what to directly fetch the data according to the search's state and for that, you need to specify the query and it depends on the api's settings but I'll give you an example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://openlibrary.org/subjects/drama.jon?published_in=2000&name=${search}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
```

Comment: I actually had both of those snippets in my code earlier. The first snippet says that 'book' in .then(data => data.filter(book.name.includes(search)) cannot be found. And in the second snippet, it cannot fetch the link.

Comment: Oh I made a mistake on the first snippet that I just fixed. As for the second one I was trying to showcase how you could specify some queries but it ultimately depends on the API you're using and what queries and params it accepts. You should check the docs.

Comment: Yeah thanks for fixing it. I am going to take a look at the docs. However, do you know why for your first snippet (after the fix), this error pops up? Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Comment: Because it was supposed to be book.title and not book.name . When those kinds of errors appear it means that the method (is this case: includes) isn't available so it must be a value or key p.roblem